# sprite image quality poor

Tags: asp.net, css, sprite

i have created a sprite image for all my images being used in the website(.png,.jpeg,.gif)

earlier when i was using imageurl to get the images.. the quality of the image for example the calendar icon to display the calendar.. was good.. and perfect

however when i have started getting the images.. using a css file .. by using background:image url(path and position of the sprite image).. the quality of the image deteriorates..

i have tried creating my sprite image in all possible formats..!!.. 
is there any solution to maintain the quality and still get the images through the sprite generated image!

CSS for an image:

```
.sprite-calendar
{
   background: url(images/csg-4d4146d95bbab.png) no-repeat top left;
   background-position: -480px -1249px; 
   width: 16px; 
   height: 16px; 
}
```

Comment: Implementing a sprite shouldn't lower the quality of your image. Is your browser zoomed in? What are the export settings on your Image editing software?

Comment: what settings should i provide the image editing software with.. no the browser isnt zoomed in..

Comment: It depends on your software, what are you using?

Comment: i dont think so thats the problem??.. cos now the website logo.. its showing perfect.. but.. comes with a red crossed white box.. on the page when called.. like this..!!

Comment: Ok, can we see your example? That would help a lot in solving your issue :)

Comment: sprite-calendar { background: url(images/csg-4d4146d95bbab.png) no-repeat top left; background-position: -480px -1249px; width: 16px; height: 16px; } this is my css.. and to call this.. m calling it like this.. <asp:ImageButton ID="FromAsOfDateTextBoxImage" runat="server" CssClass="sprite-calendar" />

Comment: I meant a live example, sorry if I wasn't clear. If you can't provide access to your server, you can make a version jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by any chance, scaling the image using CSS? You shouldn't be doing that as it will reduce the quality.

Comment: .sprite-calendar{background: url(images/csg-4d4146d95bbab.png) no-repeat top left; background-position: -480px -1249px; width: 16px; height: 16px; }    this is what my sprite image css for calendar looks like

Comment: @prateek - Are the width and height of 16px matching that of the actual image? If not, remove the width and height properties and try.

Comment: hmm.. ok fine i'll try doing that.. even when i tried to get the logo of my website through a sprite image.. using css.. the logo comes fine.. but comes with a white border.. and a white box and cross sign at the left hand side top.??!!

Comment: @adarsh - without mentioning the width and height property.. the image comes with a red crossed white box..

Comment: @prateek - red crossed white box? Are you using img tags as well? You shouldn't be using them if you're using sprites. Get rid of all img tags.

Comment: .sprite-calendar
{
   background: url(images/csg-4d4146d95bbab.png) no-repeat top left;
   background-position: -480px -1249px; 
   width: 16px; 
   height: 16px; 
} this is my css.. and to call this.. m calling it like this.. <asp:ImageButton ID="FromAsOfDateTextBoxImage" runat="server" CssClass="sprite-calendar" />

Comment: @prateek - you might want to use asp:Button here instead of asp:ImageButton. asp:ImageButton expects the attribute ImageUrl to be present. But since you're using sprites, ImageUrl doesn't make sense. 

So you have two options: Either point the ImageUrl to a transparent 1x1 gif or get rid of asp:ImageButton and use asp:Button